# Python code for security analysis using Bandit

Tags: python, security, analyzer, bandit-python

I would like to get python code for an analysis using Bandit static analyzer. The main emphasis is security, for python 2.7.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to write code to test your software using *Bandit* static analyzer tool.

All you need to do (in the most basic scenario) is:

1. Install Bandit with `pip3 install bandit` (Python3) or `pip install bandit` (Python2)
2. Navigate to your project in terminal, e.g. `cd /home/user/projects/abc/`
3. Run the Bandit on your source code with `bandit -r .`

What you may also want to do, is to exclude *virtualenv* libraries' files from testing by adding `-x env` to the command (now it would look like this: `bandit -r . -x env`).

For more information, please refer to [Bandit main page](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit).