# SonarQube does not display Bandit's Python security vulnerability report

Tags: python, sonarqube, bandit-python

## Overview

I'm using SonarQube 7.4.0.18908 to gather code coverage and perform static code analysis for a Python 3.6 project. The server is running in AWS. Things are working as expected (see screenshot below).

Now I'd like to add security scanning for the project. I "chose" [Bandit](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit), but really that seems to be the only tool which currently integrates with SonarQube for Python, as described in [Import Bandit Issues Reports](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Import+Bandit+Issues+Reports). The SonarPython plugin supports Bandit analysis, which is installed on the SonarQube server. To generate vulnerability report locally, I'm using Bandit 1.5.1 pip3 module.

## Issue

The vulnerability report is not displayed - possibly not even uploaded - to SonarQube (see same screenshot below).

## Steps to Reproduce

I added this line to the project's `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
sonar.python.bandit.reportPaths=bandit-report.json
```

I then ran the report:

```
pip3 install bandit==1.5.1
bandit --format json --output bandit-report.json --recursive src
```

I verified that `bandit-report.json` contains correct data:

```
{
  "errors": [],
  "generated_at": "2019-01-30T14:49:18Z",
  "metrics": {
...
"results": [
    {
      "code": "8 def prepare_df_for_comparison(df, name, ignore_columns=None, sort_columns=None):\n9     assert df is not None\n10 \n11     # upper-case all columns\n12     df.columns = [x.upper() for x in df.columns]\n",
      "filename": "./build/lib/tasks/compare_df.py",
      "issue_confidence": "HIGH",
      "issue_severity": "LOW",
      "issue_text": "Use of assert detected. The enclosed code will be removed when compiling to optimised byte code.",
...
```

I then published to SonarQube:

```
sonar-scanner
```

The output of the scanner:

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: NONE
INFO: Project root configuration file: /root_dir/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0.1227
INFO: Java 1.8.0_191 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit amd64
INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
INFO: SonarQube server 7.4.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=126ms
INFO: Server id: <snip>
INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=102ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=130ms
INFO: Loaded core extensions:
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=84ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=33ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=554ms
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=27ms
INFO: Project key: security-scan
INFO: Project base dir: /root_dir/src
INFO: -------------  Scan Security Scan
INFO: Base dir: /root_dir/src
INFO: Working dir: /root_dir/src/.scannerwork
INFO: Source paths: config, dag_factories, operators, tasks
INFO: Test paths: tests
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=187ms
INFO: Language is forced to py
INFO: Index files
INFO: Excluded sources:
INFO:   **/*.pyc
INFO:   **/*.ini
INFO: Excluded tests:
INFO:   **/*.pyc
INFO: 95 files indexed
INFO: 82 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: Quality profile for py: Sonar way
INFO: Sensor Python Squid Sensor [python]
WARN: Metric 'comment_lines_data' is deprecated. Provided value is ignored.
INFO: Sensor Python Squid Sensor [python] (done) | time=2831ms
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor [python]
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor [python] (done) | time=318ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=6ms
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=54ms
INFO: SCM Publisher is disabled
INFO: 3 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 61 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 2349ms, dir size=617 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 15384ms, zip size=233 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 108ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://sonarqube.mydomain/dashboard?id=security-scan
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at https://sonarqube.mydomain/api/ce/task?id=<snip>
INFO: Task total time: 26.187 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 27.558s
INFO: Final Memory: 16M/295M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the full `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
sonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.mydomain
sonar.scm.disabled=true

sonar.projectKey=security-scan
sonar.projectName=Security Scan
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.language=py

sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=tests
sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=coverage.xml

sonar.python.bandit.reportPaths=bandit-report.json

sonar.exclusions=**/*.pyc,**/*.ini
sonar.test.exclusions=**/*.pyc
```

But nowhere in the SonarQube UI do I see this report. What am I missing?

## Related Issues

[Python code for security analysis using Bandit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864556/python-code-for-security-analysis-using-bandit).

This is the only related issue I could find on SO. My issue is different. As I mentioned, Bandit report is generated correctly locally. But the issue seems to be with the upload to SonarQube.

[Empty vulnerability report screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOHa0.png)

Comment: Which version of SonarPython do you have? (Because **Bandit** is supported since SonarPython 1.11)

Comment: Note: SonarPython 1.11 is embedded by default in SonarQube 7.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We added very recently the support of Bandit in SonarPython.

Are you using SonarPython 1.11 in your SonarQube 7.4 instance?
You can check that in $SQ_HOME/extensions/plugins. If this is not the case, simply replace the sonar-python-plugin-xxx.jar by the 1.11 and that should fix your problem.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPython

Thanks

Comment: Nice, I grabbed sonar-python plugin version `1.11.0.2473` on the release page
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPython

After I put `sonar-python-plugin-1.10.0.2131.jar` in `/usr/local/sonar/extensions/plugins/` and restart the SonarQube service, I'm seeing the report in the UI.

Scanner is showing the upload in the logs too, which is helpful +1:

`INFO: Sensor Import of Bandit issues [python] (done) | time=738ms`

Comment: Is it possible to triage the bandit report from the sonar cube ? Last time I checked it just displays the report but can't do any triage. I might be wrong. @Alexandre - SonarSource, can you please confirm ?

Answer (score 1):

U have to add a .bandit file in your project root and define rules there.

then u also need to install pip install bandit into your env. 
Hope it works for you. this way works for me and it generates a report as defined by rules.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Per my comment, my issue was resolved by upgrading to SonarPython 1.11.0.2473.